# How to enable `Developer Tools experiments` in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have visited the page `chrome://flags` but the option to enable the `Developer Tools  experiments` is not visible there! (PS:Where did it disappear?)

Comment: It's already enabled by default, no need for the flag.

Answer (score 3):

As of Chrome 83, the flag has been removed and you can see the experiments in DevTools settings by default now.

Issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1048124